Olympiad Euclidean Geometry: incircles and circumcircles
This is a problem that I worked on for quite a while, but I couldn't prove it completely.
For an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$, let $D$ be on segment $AC$ such that $BD=BC$. Let I be the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. Connect $AI,IC$. Let $L,N,M$ be the midpoints of $AI, IC, AC$. respectively. Let J be the circumcenter of $\triangle AIC$.  $NM$ intersects $(DMJ)$ at $P \neq M$. $LJ$ intersects $(DMJ)$ at $Q \neq J$. Let the incircle of $\triangle ADB$ intersect sides $AD$, $DC$ at $E,F$, respectively. Prove that $EF$,$PQ$ and $LN$ concur. (2024 CMO Day 1 #2)
I couldn't solve it, but I had some progress. First, I proved that $LJ \bot PN$, which can be proved by $LJ \bot AI$ and $PN \parallel AI$. Then since $DM \bot MJ$, $DJ$ is the diameter of $(DMJ)$. Let $PQ \cap LN = X$, and we have $\angle XPM = \angle LJM = \angle DAI = \angle NLI = \angle PNX$, which implies $PX=XN$. Since $\angle PMD = \angle PNL$, we have $\angle PMD = \angle MPQ$, which tells us arc $PD$ = arc $MQ$, $PQ=DM$. Now $PQ=JM$, so $DM=MJ$, which implies that $\angle JDM = \angle DJM = 45$ degrees. Also, $PM=MN$. Thus,  Let $EF \cap LN = X'$, and we can also get $\angle DEF=\angle EFD = \angle FX'L$. By angle chasing, $\angle DEF = \angle ECI$, which might be useful, but I'm not sure.
Can somebody give me a hint of what to do next?


Potential solving avenue: Angle chase to show that $EX'NC$ is an isosceles trapezoid. The problem reduces to showing that $X'M\perp MN$. You can now rephrase the problem to completely get rid of $(DMJ)$.

In my solution there is a geogebra picture having no $45^\circ$-angle in $\Delta JDM$. Something in the argumentation of this point is not correct. But the rest and the picture already provide a high quality for the question, upvoted! Which is exactly the country and the level of this Olympiad problem?

@ dan_fulea it is 2024 China Mathematical Olympiad Day 1 #2. It is maybe? the same level as the USAMO. The format of the Olympiad is the same as the USAMO.

The figure is already such a mess, so that adding some more points does not change visibly the situation. So there will be some more points, and we will show "more" using them, hoping that in this manner the hidden geometric properties become more natural, and have better bridges to explain them. To have a final picture we can work with later, here is it:


Observe that $B,I,J$ are collinear. Indeed,
$$\begin{aligned}\widehat{BIC} &= 180^\circ -\frac 12 \hat B-\frac 12\hat C = 90^\circ +\frac 12\hat A\ ,\\
\widehat{JIC} &= \widehat{JIN} = 90^\circ -\widehat{IJN} 
\overset{\odot(LINJ)}= 90^\circ- \widehat{ILN}= 90^\circ- \widehat{IAC}
= 90^\circ- \frac 12\hat A\ .
\end{aligned}
$$The two angles add to $180^\circ$, so we have the claimed collinearity. Let $\Delta\ne J$ be the intersection of this line $BIJ$ with the blue circle $\odot(PDQMJ)=\odot(\Gamma)$. So $\widehat{D\Delta J}=\widehat{DMJ}=90^\circ$, so $\Delta$ is equivalently the projection of $D$ on $BIJ$. It is convenient to denote the center of this mentioned circle, the mid point of $JD$, by $\Gamma$, and then this circle is simpler to be named by its center, $\odot(\Gamma)$. (No other circle with the same center will be of interest below.)
Let $R$ be the intersection of the lines $ALI$ and $PQ$.
Let $S\ne M$ be the intersection point of the line $LM$ with the circle $\odot(\Gamma)$.
Let $T$ be the intersection of the perpendicular bisector $LQJ$ of $AI$ with the side  $AB$. Then $TA=TI$, $\widehat{TIL}=\widehat{TAL}=\widehat{LAC}$, so $TI\|AC$, i.e. $T$ is on the parallel through $I$ to $AC$.
Let $U$ be the intersection of the perpendicular bisector $NJ$ of $CI$ with the side  $BC$. Then $UC=UI$, and in a similar manner $U$ is on the parallel through $I$ to $AC$.
Let $V$ be the intersection of the line $TIU$ with the perpendicular bisector of $CD$. It turns out that $IV=DE$. This is a metric relation. I decided to show it, and base the solution on it. To have an uncluttered isolated situation, here is a dedicated Lemma extracting only the necessary. (The solution has to do somewhere some "hard word", i decided to do it here, where the complexity can be isolated as a property of "only" the points $D,E,F$.)


Lemma:
Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with sides of lengths $a,b,c$, following usual notations. Let $I$ be the incenter, in barycentric coordinates $I=(a:b:c)$.
Let $T,U$ be on the sides $BA,BC$, so that $TU$ is the parallel through $I$ to $AC$. Let $B',V$ be the projections of $B$ on $AC$, and on $TU$. Let $D$ be the reflection of $C$ w.r.t. $B'$, so that $\Delta BCD$ is isosceles in $B$. We must also invent $E,F$, the projections of the incenter of $\Delta ABD$ on $DA, DB$. Then:
$$\bbox[yellow]{\qquad IV=DE=\frac1{2b}(c-a)(a-b+c)\qquad}\ .
$$
In particular $DEIV$ is a parallelogram,
$IVCE$ an isosceles trapezium,
and $F$ is on $EV$.

Proof of the Lemma:  Pure computations. We have $B'C=BC\cos \hat C=a\cdot\frac{a^+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=\frac 1{2b}(a^2+b^2-c^2)$. We thus also know $CD=2B'C=(a^2+b^2-c^2)/b$. We know the position of $I$ on the angle bisector $BI$,
its proportion of distances
measured on the line $BI$
from $B$, and respectively from (intersection with) $AC$ , is $(b+c):a$. So $\Delta BTU$ is a rescaling of $\Delta BAC$ with the factor $f=(a+c)/(a+b+c)$. This gives $VU=f\cdot B'C$, $TU=fb$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
IU &=\frac{IU}{TU}\cdot TU= 
\frac{BU}{BU+BT}\cdot TU=\frac{BC}{BC+BA}\cdot f\; AC
\\
&=\frac a{a+c}\cdot \frac{a+c}{a+b+c}\cdot b=\frac{ab}{a+b+c}\ ,
\\[2mm]
VU &= f\, B'C= \frac{a+c}{a+b+c}\cdot \frac 1{2b}(a^2+b^2-c^2)\ ,
\\[2mm]
IV &= IU-VU
\\
&=\frac1{2b(a+b+c)}\Big(\ \underbrace{a(b^2+c^2-a^2) - c(a^2 +b ^2-c^2)}
_{\substack{=b^2(a-c)-(a+c)(c^2-a^2)\\=(a-c)(b^2-(a+c)^2)}} \ \Big)
=\frac1{2b}(c-a)(a-b+c)\ ,
\\[2mm]
DE&=
\frac 12(DA+DB-AB)\qquad\text{ (Half-perimeter of $\Delta DAB$ minus $AB$)}
\\
&=\frac 12((b-CD)+a-b)
=\frac 12\left(\left(b-\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}b\right)+a-c\right)
=\frac1{2b}(c-a)(a-b+c)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
To see that $F\in EV$ we compute
$$2\widehat{FEC}=2\widehat{FED}=180^\circ-\widehat{EDF}
=\widehat{FDC}=\widehat{BDC}=\widehat{BCD}=2\hat C
=2\widehat{ICE}=2\widehat{VEC}\ .
$$
$\square$


Using the Lemma, the segments $IV$, $DE$ are parallel and of the same length, so $DEIV$ is a parallelogram. Let $X$ be the intersection, alias mid point(s) of the diagonals.
Because the parallels $IV\|LN\|AC$ are in this order equidistant, ($L$ is mid point of $IA$,) the point $X$, mid point of $VE$ is on $LN$.
We have so far $X\in EF$, and $X\in LN$. We need still $X\in PQ$.
Recall that $LJ$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AI$, and $AI\|MN$. Recall that by definition $R=ALI\cap PQ$.
We let $Y$ (and want $Y=X$) be the mid point of the hypotenuse $QR$
in the right triangle $\Delta LQR$.
We compute the angle in $R$ in it, in the same time show $PQR\|AB$:
$$%\small
\hat R=\widehat{QRA}=%\widehat{QRL}=
%\widehat{PRL}=
 \widehat{RPM}=\widehat{QPM}=\widehat{QJM}=
90^\circ-\widehat{JMP}=\widehat{NMC}=\widehat{IAC}=\frac 12\hat A=\widehat{IAB}\ .
$$This gives the wanted parallelism $PQR\| AB$. Also, $\widehat{RLY}=\widehat{YRL}=\frac 12\hat A=\widehat{RAC}$ shows $LY\|AC$, so $Y\in LN$.
Recall that $S,M$ are the two points on $LM$, and on $\odot(\Gamma)=\odot(PQMJ)$. We show that $S$ is also on the circle $\odot(Y)=\odot(QLR)$. For this we compute the angle
$$  \widehat{LSQ}=180^\circ-\widehat{QSM}=\widehat{QJM}=\widehat{LJM}
\overset{\odot(ALMJ)}=\widehat{LAM}=\frac 12\hat A=\widehat{QRL}\ .
$$So $SQLR$ cyclic, and $Y$ has the same distance to its vertices,
$$YL=YQ=YR=YS\ .$$
We want to show that $QS\| D\Delta$, by showing that they are perpendicular on the same line, $BIJ$. We already know $D\Delta\perp BIJ$, so let us compute the angle between the lines $QS$, and $BIJ$ by using the triangle formed by these two lines, and the line $LSM$. The angle in $S$ is already known, it equals $\widehat{QSL}=\widehat{QRL}=\frac 12\hat A$. The other acute angle is the same as the acute angle between $IC$ (a parallel to $LM$) and $IB$, and this angle is $180^\circ - \widehat{BIC}=\widehat{IBC}+\widehat{ICB}=\frac 12\hat B+\frac 12\hat C=90^\circ-\frac 12 \hat A$. So indeed, the third angle is a right angle.
$QS$ is a chord in the circle with diameter $QR$ centered in $Y$, and also in the circle $\odot(\Gamma)$. So $\Gamma Y$ is the common symmetry axis of the two circles, and $\Gamma Y$ is the perpendicular bisector of the parallel chords $QS$, $D\Delta$. Also, $D\Delta$ is a chord in the circle centered in $X$ with diameter $DI$. So $X$ is also on the perpendicular bisector of $D\Delta$. We obtain the same characterization for the points $X,Y$, they are both on $LN$ and on the perpendicular bisector of the $\odot(\Gamma)$-chords $QS$, and $D\Delta$. This implies
$$X=Y=EF\cap LN\cap PQ\cap (\text{perp. bisector of $D\Delta$ and $QS$})
=(\text{center}(\odot(LRSQ))\ .$$

$\square$
